How to search embeddedDocuments fields and Root Document fields using Atlas Search
I have the following document in my collection
{
    "_id": "101",
    "PublisherName": "Big book publishers",
    "Books": [
        {
            "_id": "6791913210",
            "Title": "Piano made simple",
            "Author": "John Bent"
        },
        {
            "_id": "6638200210",
            "Title": "Guitar made simple",
            "Author": "Kim Larry"
        }
    ]
}

Ive defined the search index as follows
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "PublisherName": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
         "type": "string"
      },
      "Books": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "fields": {
          "Author": {
            "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "type": "embeddedDocuments"
      }
    }
  }
}

I can search in the PublisherName or Author fields using seperate search definition
[Search PublisherName]
{
    "index": "book-search-Index",
    "text": {
        "query": "Big book publishers",
        "path": ["PublisherName"]
    }
}

or
[Search Books.Author]
{
    "index": "book-search-Index",
    "embeddedDocument": {
        "path": "Books",
        "operator": {
            "text": {
                "path": ["Books.Author"],
                "query": "Guitar"
            }
        }
    }
}

But im not able to define one search defination that is capable for searching both the PublisherName filed and Book.Author field. I tried the below but im getting error
"Reason: at most one of [autocomplete, compound, embeddedDocument, equals, exists, geoShape, geoWithin, in, knnBeta, moreLikeThis, near, phrase, queryString, range, regex, search, span, term, text, wildcard] may be present"
{
    "index": "book-search-Index",
    "text": {
        "query": "Big book publishers",
        "path": ["PublisherName"]
    }
    "embeddedDocument": {
        "path": "Books",
        "operator": {
            "text": {
                "path": ["Books.Author"],
                "query": "Guitar"
            }
        }
    }
}


The solution to this issues is
{
    "index": "book-search-Index",
    "compound": {
        "should": [
            {
                "embeddedDocument": {
                    "path": "Books",
                    "operator": {
                        "compound": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "path": ["Books.Author"],
                                        "query": "Guitar"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "text": {
                    "query": "Big book publishers",
                    "path": ["PublisherName"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

